# C Multi Thread function call huge local memory need in run time?

Tags: c, multithreading, memory

```
int run = 1;
int testPrint(char *format, ...)
{
    va_list aptr;
    int ret;
    char buffer[1024];
    
    va_start(aptr, format);
    ret = vsprintf(buffer, format, aptr);
    va_end(aptr);
    //do something pass(&buffer);
    
    return(ret);
}

void fooThread(void *argv)
{
    while(run)
    {
        testPrint("%s %d\n",__function__ ,__LINE__ );
    }
}


int main(){
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++){

        pthread_t t;
        pthread_create(&t,NULL,fooThread,NULL);
        pthread_detach(&t);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

For some reason I need design a function call like printf for debug

How many memory testPrint need in run time ?

1024      bytes ?
1024*100  bytes ?

Comment: This is effectively doing everything in sequence. Only one thread at a time call `fooThread` so you could just skip threading and calll `fooThread` normally.

Comment: so like  race condition call same function point?

Comment: I don't see how this could cause a race condition since there's only one active thread running at a time. The "main" thread starts a single thread and then just waits for it to finish.

Comment: sorry , should be pthread_detach

Comment: Now the program will likely have _undefined behavior_ since the threads keep running after `main` exits and they access the global `run` variable that will be destroyed when `main` exits. Why not have one loop to create the threads and a second loop to join them?

Comment: skip run flag, quest is char buffer[1024] need ,thx

Answer (score 0):

> How many memory testPrint need in run time ?

Every thread usually has its own stack and each `testPrint` function call will pick what it needs from the current thread's stack.

So, the local variables

```
va_list aptr;
int ret;
char buffer[1024];
```

will be allocated from each thread's stack, which means it'll allocate up to 100 `va_list`, `int` and `char[1024]`s at the same time, but from different stacks.